# How to set the selected option of a select list by value NOT by selectedIndex using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the selected item of a select which equals a certain value.
I am currently using:

```
$("#mySelectList").val(4);
```

This however is setting the list to the 4th selectedIndex instead of the selectedIndex which has a value of 4.

I am using version 1.9.1. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems to be working good: http://jsfiddle.net/cGr4W/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#mySelectList option[value='4']").prop('selected', true);
```